# How to cache dependencies (npm/yarn) and docker layers when running npm install inside a docker image being built via a script ran in github action?

Tags: docker, caching, github-actions

So before you jump to mark as a duplicate question, let's make sure we understand the subtlety here.

I am compiling a Single Page Application (React) inside a docker image, all this inside a github action, and I want to optimise caching / build time.

- Github actions runs docker build via a custom script
- Inside the dockerfile, I'm calling `yarn / npm install` to install from node modules (currently using yarn 1, so all I need are node_modules)

Here is what my github action looks like

```
name: Build and push docker image on AWS
on:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      [...]
      - name: Build docker images & push to AWS
        run: ./scripts/deploy/build_and_push_docker_image_to_aws.sh
        env:
          DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
```

Note that I do not want to build the docker via an action directly (several SO cover that already), as I need to do several things around (check for duplicate image, push them to AWS, etc), and I want to ensure that I can also run those scripts outside github action if I need (it makes them more maintainable)

My build_and_push_docker_image_to_aws.sh script

```bash
[...]
docker build \
  --file ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile \
  --build-arg FRIENDLY_TAG=$(./scripts/get_friendly_tag.sh) \
  --tag xxxx \
  docker/nginx/.
[...]
```

Inside my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15.14 as build-deps
COPY package.json yarn.lock .yarnrc ./
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,target=/root/.npmrc yarn
```

So if I understand I must 2 two things :

- share docker layer cache between github action and the docker build (enables docker layer caching) - in otherwords, do what the `docker/setup-buildx-action@v1` + `docker/build-push-action@v2` would usually do, when executing a bash script
- share a local node_modules directory between the github action runner and the docker context, and cache this folder via github actions (similar to what `docker build --secret` would do, but with a folder)

Am I on the right track ? It feels like I cannot really reuse existing solutions as they all perform the docker build via a specific github action directly (but I am running a bash script)